# SQL DB2 - Execute a Query using a results from another table or query

Tags: sql, db2, procedure, db2-400

I am running the following query:

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA ||'.'||TABLE_NAME AS Schema_Table 
     from qsys2.systables 
     where table_schema = 'PTLDBA' 
     AND TABLE_NAME LIKE'DAILY%' 
    AND DATE (LAST_ALTERED_TIMESTAMP) = CURRENT DATE;
```

The result set is `schema.table name`. I need to use the result set to query the actual table

The final query would look like this:

```
Select * from Schema_Table limit 10;
```

The table name changes depending on the day. I believe a SQL Procedure would work best but I am not sure how to write it.

Comment: To change structure components of SQL statement like table name, you will have to construct dynamic SQL and then execute.

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?  We can point you to the correct docs...

Comment: I work with IBMi Power 9 the software is version 7.4